# Correlate only columns with same name

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply

I have two huge dataframes with the same columns and row names but different values.
Now i wanted to compute the correlation for each column between the two dataframes but only for the columns with the same name.

```
  yyyymm `10000` `10001` `10002` `10003` `10004` `10005` `10006`
   <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 198601      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
2 198602      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
3 198603      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
4 198604      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
5 198605      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
6 198606      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

both datframes look like this.

Meaning i want the correlation of the column `10001` of the first dataframe with `10001` of the second dataframe and so on.

PS: the missing values are only in the first rows.

Comment: Please share a reproducible piece of each of your data frames with `dput(head(data))` so that others can use it to be able to help you get your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
set.seed(111)
df1 <- data.frame(c1 = rnorm(10),
                   c2 = rnorm(10),
                   c3 = rnorm(10))
 df2 <- data.frame(c1 = rnorm(10),
                  c3 = rnorm(10),
                  c2 = rnorm(10))
Map(cor, df1[sort(names(df1))], df2[sort(names(df2))])
$c1
[1] -0.02421313

$c2
[1] 0.2706937

$c3
[1] -0.1615181
```

OR:

```
unlist(Map(cor, df1[sort(names(df1))], df2[sort(names(df2))]))
         c1          c2          c3 
-0.02421313  0.27069371 -0.16151811
```

Using purrr:

```
library(purrr)
pmap(list(df1[sort(names(df1))], df2[sort(names(df2))]), cor)
$c1
[1] -0.02421313

$c2
[1] 0.2706937

$c3
[1] -0.1615181
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "calculate the correlation"?
You can calculate the correlation between two columns as

```
cor.test(dataframe1$ColumnX, dataframe2$ColumnX, method = "pearson")
```

This will give you the pearson correlation between the values within the columns named "ColumnX" in `dataframe1` and `dataframe2`.

I assume you want to calculate those correlations for all columns, then it might be the simplest solution to loop through all of the column names`*`:

```
names <- names(dataframe1)
correlations <- list()
for(name in names){
   correlations[[name]] <- cor.test(dataframe1[, name], dataframe2[, name], method = "pearson")
}
```

`*` note that I made a whole lot of assumptions here. Without more specific information on your data and your goals, there is no way to really help you. I'll assume, for example, that your data frames are called `dataframe1`and `dataframe2` and that they have both exactly the same column names and you want to calculate a pearson correlation for **all** columns within those data frames.